# MongoDB encryption and description

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, mongoose, encryption

I want to encrypt some user important fields in user collection but I don't want the server should take care of encryption or decryption, I want MongoDB to encrypt data by itself and decrypt by itself server should just trigger normal query like find or insert.

While insert query mongoDB should encrypt that particular field's data and when i trigger find query mongoDB should decrypt data and send back to server

Comment: What threats do you want to protect against? Depending on the answer, encryption at rest, transport encryption and/or client-side field level encryption are the feature you are looking for (also see https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-encryption).

Comment: I am using atlas actually what I want is if someone can look into my DB user collection they can only see encrypted data, original data should be only visible by my server means when I trigger find query from my backend server MongoDB atlas should know I am an authentic server(maybe I sent any access private key) then MongoDB atlas decrypt that particular data in their own side and send back original data to server so server does not need worry to decrypt that data

Comment: Sounds as if Client-Side Field Level Encryption will fit your needs.

Comment: okay i will see this thank you for helping

Comment: I still recommend that you invest time to better understand what threat you want to protect against. Client-side field level encryption will prevent the database administrator from seeing the real data, it can be helpful if database permissions are incorrectly configured and for certain attacks targeted directly at the database. It does not help if the hackers attack your application server. And for many other threat scenarios, there are simpler approaches.